# Get names of GET method variables

Tags: php, get

I have about 5 variables in GET method. They almost always have different names, encoded mostly. How i can get name (not value) of those variables.

example:

```
$_GET['orchid'] = red;
$_GET['xyc'] = wrack;
```

and after that, next time i open the page:

```
$_GET['rose'] = red;
$_GET['gzuy'] = bottle;
```

Values are not important for now, in this case I need names of variables: "orchid", "xyc" or in second case "rose" and "gzuy".

Comment: Use `array_keys($_GET)`

Comment: Some wording stuff: $_GET is an array, which contains elements that consist of a key (orchid, rose, ...) and a value (red, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_keys($_GET)
```

For more informations, see the link bellow:

http://php.net/manual/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value){
    echo $key;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/array_keys) should do the trick:

```
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    //Line below is optional to get around empty values.
    if (!empty($value))
    echo $key, '  ';
}
```

The above code will print out all of the set `$_GET` variables, having `file.php?moo` will mark `moo` as set but with a value of nothing. The below snippet will simply return an array just containing the names of the `$_GET` variables which can then be used in `$_GET[$keys[0]]` for example to recall its value.

```
array_keys($_GET);
```

Docs:

[foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/function.array-keys.php)